# Sharepoint 2007 : WorkFlow with Confirmation Activities

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I am implementing an SharePoint workflow that perform the following activities.

1. User upload an excel
2. System would validate and if the data is correct would temporary save the data in a SPList
3. User would access a page that would confirm the correctness.
4. When user click confirmed, the data would be inserted into a database.

I would like to ask if step 3 is possible in SharePoint 2007 workflow.
Any reference or guide would be very much appreciated

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

what you can do here is to have a workflow that would wait until a certain field in SharePoint (if this is the method you do it) becomes confirmed, when that happens continue on with the workflow you made (provided this is made using SharePoint designer).